# please explain how to configure ansible hosts on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh

am getting troble to configure ansible hosts..i created my servers but when i given ping command also not getting...please explain how to configure ansible hosts on ubuntu

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ansible myserver -m ping -u root -k
SSH password: 
192.168.197.120 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Authentication failure.", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this is failing because you are running SSH as the user 'root' and not as the user you created such as 'ubuntu' or your own username.

Test it out with the SSH client directly and get that working, e.g.

```
ssh root@1921.68.197.120
or
ssh sravan@1921.68.197.120
```